# mysql error; Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1136

I am just learning MySQL and am trying to create a basic table.
But I am getting this error:

> Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1.

Query is

```
insert into user(username,password,email,created,last_updated) values (
    ('TEST USERNAME','TEST PASSWORD','Test@test.com',current_timestamp(),current_timestamp()), 
    ('TEST USERNAME 2','TEST PASSWORD 2','Test2@test.com',current_timestamp(),current_timestamp())
);
```

The columns in the table are :

- id
- username
- password
- email
- created
- last_updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the brackets for `Values(..)`, *i.e.*, it should be `Values (..), (..)` instead.

```
insert into user(username,password,email,created,last_updated) 
values
('TEST USERNAME','TEST PASSWORD','Test@test.com',current_timestamp(),current_timestamp()), 
('TEST USERNAME 2','TEST PASSWORD 2','Test2@test.com',current_timestamp(),current_timestamp());
```

From [Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html), the syntax is:

> ```
> INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
>     [INTO] tbl_name
>     [PARTITION (partition_name [, partition_name] ...)]
>     [(col_name [, col_name] ...)]
>     {VALUES | VALUE} (value_list) [, (value_list)] ...
>     [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE assignment_list]
> ```
>
> ...
>
> INSERT statements that use VALUES syntax can insert multiple rows. To
>   do this, include multiple lists of comma-separated column values, with
>   lists enclosed within parentheses and separated by commas. Example:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

your columns in your table has id yet you don't have it when you wrote

```sql
insert into user(username,password,email,created,last_updated)
```

you should write

```sql
insert into user(id,username,password,email,created,last_updated)
```